# MacOS 10.10 Apache user sites folder permissions

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

Following this guide; https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/ to set up Apache to use a user (me) Sites folder. (I have seen the same steps elsewhere but this one explains fairly simply.

I have the System site folder "It Works!" working OK on `http://localhost` but I get a 403 error trying to access "`http://localhost/~username`"

MAMP works fine but it is more versatile to use the Sites folder for static sites.

Possible complications: I am running my system on an SSD but have my Home folder on another internal drive.

Comment: this belongs on either [sf] or [su]

Comment: OK, sorry, I find the stack exchange planet a tricky one to navigate